# How to make a modal window

Tags: modal-dialog, powerbuilder

I have two windows, `winA` and `winB`. I open `winB` from `winA` using `OpenSheetWithParm`. I don't want to be able to commute from `winB` to `winA` until `winB` is closed. How am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can make winB a response window.

Comment: And how do I make it response in my code? I want to be response only in few situations.

Comment: Create a descendant of winB that only changes the WindowType to Response, and open that one.